# Xmodmap not working and changes not being register outside XEV

Tags: linux, arch-linux, manjaro, xmodmap

I am noob, so I'm a little overwhelmed by all of this. I am using manjaro.

What I am trying to do is to remap the **greater** and **less** keys to the position of the **colon** and **period** since the keyboard I use and the layout I currently have make that the currently the key for those symbols don't exist.

Greater -- Alt_R + "comma" key
Less -- Alt_R + "period" key

After using `xev` to make sure what keycodes were associated with the keys I wanted to change, I created the `~/.Xmodmap` with the following intructions:

```
keycode 59 = comma semicolon comma semicolon less
keycode 60 = period colon period colon greater
```

After that I ran `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`
The contents of `xmodmap -pke` and the output of the `xev` changed as expected, but besides that everything stayed the same as I have done nothing.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for the help!

obs: Would be possible to instead of using `ALT_R` use `CRT_L + ALT_L` ?

Comment: Yup, it is ISO_Level3_Shift

Comment: Yup, its wayland:/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am going to check it out:) Btw, what are the implications of choosing Xorg?

Comment: I am having the same behavior. Did you figure this out?